Question on economic data
I need to find two data sets:

inflation (seasonally adjusted) (I found the inflation data, but seasonally unadjusted)

Sectoral prices (automobile prices, energy prices and so on)


The data I need to find is for Turkey.
How can I find these data? Please give hints to find these data

where did you try to search for them so far? Did you check WB, IMF etc?

I normally would do it in three ways.
(1) Access the National Statistics Portal. For Turkey, that would be the Turkish Statistical Institute (TURKSTAT). I think they have the time series data you need.
(2) Turkey belongs to the OECD. Their country's data are also covered by Eurostat. For example, you can find the detailed CPI baskets for Turkey in Eurostat here.
(3) Search in a paper. Most empirical papers detail where they retrieve the data from. Some papers even include the dataset in their Appendices. You just need to read and check. For example:

Berument, M. H., & Sahin, A. (2010). Seasonality in inflation volatility: Evidence from Turkey. Journal of Applied Economics, 13(1), 39-65.. The CPI data were obtained from TURKSTAT.
Köse, N., & Ünal, E. (2021). The effects of the oil price and oil price volatility on inflation in Turkey. Energy, 226, 120392. Brent & WTI Oil prices and exchange rates are obtained from FED St. Louis and CPI from Turkstat.

